# Python: dictionaries of different dimensions to excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Is there any effcient way to write different dimensions dictionaries to excel using pandas?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
mylist1=[7,8,'woo']
mylist2=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],['foo','boo','doo']]
d=dict(y=mylist1,x=mylist2)
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').transpose().fillna('')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xls',engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

The current results,

[image]

The desired results,

[image]

Please note that my database is much bigger than this simple example. So a generic answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your dataframe first before exporting to excel:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').transpose()

df = pd.concat([df["y"],pd.DataFrame(df["x"].tolist(),columns=list("x"*len(df["x"])))],axis=1)
```

Or do it upstream:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[a, *b] for a,b in zip(mylist1, mylist2)],columns=list("yxxx"))
```

Both yield the same result:

```
     y    x    x    x
0    7    1    2    3
1    8    4    5    6
2  woo  foo  boo  doo
```

Answer (score 1):

Get first appropriate format then save to excel.

```
df = df.join(df.x.apply(pd.Series)).drop('x',1)
df.columns = list('yxxx')
df
     y    x    x    x
0    7    1    2    3
1    8    4    5    6
2  woo  foo  boo  doo
```

For Dynamic columns name

```
df.columns = ['y'] + list('x' * (len(df.columns)-1))
```

Comment: Thank you [upvoted], this worked. Is there anyway to preserve the `df` keys while applying this solution? I do understand that the second line of your code does this. But I am trying to acheive the task dynamically. i.e. I may not know how many column `x` does have.